# Unexpectedly the result for my code based on `map[int][][]int`

Tags: go

I ran my code in Go versions 1.7.4, 1.8, 1.8.1 on Linux(Ubuntu 1604)/amd64

I'm trying to use a structure `m := map[int][][]int` to write a code to do something below.

For an array `numbers := []int{0,1,2,3,4}`, let `m[0] = [][]int{[]int{0}, []int{1}, []int{2}, []int{3}, []int{4}}`,
and append a number `n` within `numbers` to all list of `m[i]`, then `m[1]` as below.

`m[1] -> [[0,1], [0,2],..,[0,4],[1,2],[1,3],..,[1,4],...,,[2,3],[2,4],[3,4]]`

and so on for `m[2] -> [[0,1,2],[0,1,3],.....]`, `m[3]`, `m[4]`

Here is my code.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    n := 5
    m := make(map[int][][]int)
    list := make([][]int, 0)
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        list = append(list, []int{i})
    }
    m[0] = list
    fmt.Println(m)
    for level := 1; level < n; level++ {
        newlist := make([][]int, 0)
        for _, lst := range m[level-1] {
            for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
                if i > lst[len(lst)-1] {
                    newlst := append(lst, i)
                    newlist = append(newlist, newlst)
                    fmt.Println(level, ":", lst, i, "->", newlst, "=>", newlist)
                }
            }
        }
        m[level] = newlist
    }
    fmt.Println(m)
}
```

And the output as below.

```
map[0:[[0] [1] [2] [3] [4]]]
1 : [0] 1 -> [0 1] => [[0 1]]
1 : [0] 2 -> [0 2] => [[0 1] [0 2]]
1 : [0] 3 -> [0 3] => [[0 1] [0 2] [0 3]]
1 : [0] 4 -> [0 4] => [[0 1] [0 2] [0 3] [0 4]]
1 : [1] 2 -> [1 2] => [[0 1] [0 2] [0 3] [0 4] [1 2]]
1 : [1] 3 -> [1 3] => [[0 1] [0 2] [0 3] [0 4] [1 2] [1 3]]
1 : [1] 4 -> [1 4] => [[0 1] [0 2] [0 3] [0 4] [1 2] [1 3] [1 4]]
1 : [2] 3 -> [2 3] => [[0 1] [0 2] [0 3] [0 4] [1 2] [1 3] [1 4] [2 3]]
1 : [2] 4 -> [2 4] => [[0 1] [0 2] [0 3] [0 4] [1 2] [1 3] [1 4] [2 3] [2 4]]
1 : [3] 4 -> [3 4] => [[0 1] [0 2] [0 3] [0 4] [1 2] [1 3] [1 4] [2 3] [2 4] [3 4]]
2 : [0 1] 2 -> [0 1 2] => [[0 1 2]]
2 : [0 1] 3 -> [0 1 3] => [[0 1 2] [0 1 3]]
2 : [0 1] 4 -> [0 1 4] => [[0 1 2] [0 1 3] [0 1 4]]
2 : [0 2] 3 -> [0 2 3] => [[0 1 2] [0 1 3] [0 1 4] [0 2 3]]
2 : [0 2] 4 -> [0 2 4] => [[0 1 2] [0 1 3] [0 1 4] [0 2 3] [0 2 4]]
2 : [0 3] 4 -> [0 3 4] => [[0 1 2] [0 1 3] [0 1 4] [0 2 3] [0 2 4] [0 3 4]]
2 : [1 2] 3 -> [1 2 3] => [[0 1 2] [0 1 3] [0 1 4] [0 2 3] [0 2 4] [0 3 4] [1 2 3]]
2 : [1 2] 4 -> [1 2 4] => [[0 1 2] [0 1 3] [0 1 4] [0 2 3] [0 2 4] [0 3 4] [1 2 3] [1 2 4]]
2 : [1 3] 4 -> [1 3 4] => [[0 1 2] [0 1 3] [0 1 4] [0 2 3] [0 2 4] [0 3 4] [1 2 3] [1 2 4] [1 3 4]]
2 : [2 3] 4 -> [2 3 4] => [[0 1 2] [0 1 3] [0 1 4] [0 2 3] [0 2 4] [0 3 4] [1 2 3] [1 2 4] [1 3 4] [2 3 4]]
3 : [0 1 2] 3 -> [0 1 2 3] => [[0 1 2 3]]
3 : [0 1 2] 4 -> [0 1 2 4] => [[0 1 2 4] [0 1 2 4]]
3 : [0 1 3] 4 -> [0 1 3 4] => [[0 1 2 4] [0 1 2 4] [0 1 3 4]]
3 : [0 2 3] 4 -> [0 2 3 4] => [[0 1 2 4] [0 1 2 4] [0 1 3 4] [0 2 3 4]]
3 : [1 2 3] 4 -> [1 2 3 4] => [[0 1 2 4] [0 1 2 4] [0 1 3 4] [0 2 3 4] [1 2 3 4]]
map[4:[] 0:[[0] [1] [2] [3] [4]] 1:[[0 1] [0 2] [0 3] [0 4] [1 2] [1 3] [1 4] [2 3] [2 4] [3 4]] 2:[[0 1 2] [0 1 3] [0 1 4] [0 2 3] [0 2 4] [0 3 4] [1 2 3] [1 2 4] [1 3 4] [2 3 4]] 3:[[0 1 2 4] [0 1 2 4] [0 1 3 4] [0 2 3 4] [1 2 3 4]]]
```

The issue at here.

```
3 : [0 1 2] 3 -> [0 1 2 3] => [[0 1 2 3]]
3 : [0 1 2] 4 -> [0 1 2 4] => [[0 1 2 4] [0 1 2 4]]           
3 : [0 1 3] 4 -> [0 1 3 4] => [[0 1 2 4] [0 1 2 4] [0 1 3 4]]
3 : [0 2 3] 4 -> [0 2 3 4] => [[0 1 2 4] [0 1 2 4] [0 1 3 4] [0 2 3 4]]
3 : [1 2 3] 4 -> [1 2 3 4] => [[0 1 2 4] [0 1 2 4] [0 1 3 4] [0 2 3 4] [1 2 3 4]]
```

The correct output should be:

```
3 : [0 1 2] 3 -> [0 1 2 3] => [[0 1 2 3]]
3 : [0 1 2] 4 -> [0 1 2 4] => [[0 1 2 **3**] [0 1 2 4]]           
3 : [0 1 3] 4 -> [0 1 3 4] => [[0 1 2 **3**] [0 1 2 4] [0 1 3 4]]
3 : [0 2 3] 4 -> [0 2 3 4] => [[0 1 2 **3**] [0 1 2 4] [0 1 3 4] [0 2 3 4]]
3 : [1 2 3] 4 -> [1 2 3 4] => [[0 1 2 **3**] [0 1 2 4] [0 1 3 4] [0 2 3 4] [1 2 3 4]]
```

I don't know why, but I think it may be a bug of Go compiler or runtime.

What reason of the issue? Maybe a Go bug or just my code mistake. How to solve it if a bug for Go or my code? Cheers!

Comment: In my experience, "may be a bug of compiler or runtime", is way less likely than "may be bug in my own code." Sure it happens sometimes that the compiler or runtime is broken, but it's pretty rare. The pragmatic programmer book describes this idea with the motto '"select" isn't broken'

Comment: [a bad workman always blames his tools](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/a_bad_workman_always_blames_his_tools): proverb: A person who has done something badly will seek to lay the blame on their equipment rather than admit their own lack of skill.

Comment: @peterSO Got it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code, your slices may alias each other:

```
newlist := make([][]int, 0)
for _, lst := range m[level-1] {
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        if i > lst[len(lst)-1] {
            newlst := append(lst, i)
            newlist = append(newlist, newlst)
```

You're appending `i` to a previously computed slice, which may or may not reallocate the underlying array. When it doesn't, each `newlst` reuses the same underlying array, so in earlier versions of `newlst`, values are overwritten by later versions of `newlst`.

You need to force the new slices to use new underlying arrays by copying the data:

```
newlst := append([]int{}, lst...)
newlst = append(newlst, i)
```

[Here's a playground version of the fixed code.](https://play.golang.org/p/lNPa3KS_Ql)

Comment: It's really a trap that to be beyond comprehension. I see you are right, but it's not natural for my understanding. I think `append(lst, i)` should allocate an array which size should be `len(lst)+1`, and copy the content of `lst` and `i` to the new array. Could you explain more details for this case? And when will happen?

Comment: A new underlying array is allocated only if the appended element doesn't fit in the current array. See: https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals

Comment: Got it. Thanks a lot!